# How to change drawLine color on an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I have the following TestView class:

```
package com.example.tview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class TestView extends Activity {
    FrameLayout layout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_view);
        layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.viewd);
        //layout.removeAllViews();
        CustomView view = new CustomView(TestView.this);
        view.setText("A");
        view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        view.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/led.ttf"));
        view.setTextSize(400);
        view.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layout.addView(view);
    }
}
```

CustomView class:

```
package com.example.tview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomView extends TextView {
    Paint paint;
    Path path;
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    private int cYellow = Color.YELLOW;
    private int[] theColors = {Color.YELLOW, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK, Color.RED, Color.CYAN, Color.DKGRAY, Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK, Color.MAGENTA};

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        path= new Path();
        paint.setAlpha(255);
        paint.setColor(cYellow);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 10, paint);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
            path.lineTo(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

My XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000000"
android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="YELLOW" />
                <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GREEN" />
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_gravity="center" >

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/viewd"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bd"
android:orientation="vertical" >
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I have the Color array setup in my CustomView class, How can I set the stroke color at runtime?
So by default it should be `Color.YELLOW` but if I press the `Green` button the stroke color should be `Color.GREEN`

TestView class **UPDATE** (working):

```
    package com.example.tview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class TestView extends Activity {
    FrameLayout layout;
    Paint paint;
    public int paintColor = Color.GREEN;
    CustomView view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_view);
        layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.viewd);
        //layout.removeAllViews();
        view = new CustomView(TestView.this);
        view.setText("A");
        view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        view.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/led.ttf"));
        view.setTextSize(400);
        view.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layout.addView(view);

        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(eHandle);
    }
    View.OnClickListener eHandle = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            view.paint.setColor(paintColor);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a paint using whihc you draw on the canvas. On button press set the appropriate color to to your paint:

```
paint.setColor(Color);
```

Set proper color to this line everytme you press button

Comment: The `theColor` is a integer array and because the set color is in a different class how do I achieve it?

Comment: Have a global variabe paintColor as int. Write a listener for each button. When clicked, in the listener, assign proper value to paintColor variable. Now your paint is also a global variable. So at any point, you can setColor for it like : paint.setColor(paintColor). You dont need your theColors array then. I hope you understand what I mean. Its more of programming logic now

Comment: I understand. Even though they are in diff classes they can still communicate?

Comment: I updated my question with the updated class code but now I get a NPE when I press the GREEN button.

Comment: nevermind. I update my class that I modified to make it work. Thanks. (One question, when I change color how do I prevent the previous lines from changing and instead only change the color when drawing after the color change?)